# Issue with deploying Spring Boot application in Weblogic - 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a Spring 3 application that I'm currently trying to convert to Spring Boot but I'm having issues getting weblogic configured to run the application.

The vast majority of posts related to this issue have been solved by implementing `WebApplicationInitializer` in their main `@SpringBootApplication` class, but that doesn't seem to have any effect for me.

---

I've provided my `SpringBootApplication` class, `weblogic.xml`, and the controller I'm using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**This is my `@SpringBootApplication` class.**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AgisSpringApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AgisSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {

    }

}
```

---

**This is my `weblogic.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <wls:weblogic-web-app
        xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
        http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>agis-spring</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

---

**And this is my only controller at the moment**

```
@RestController
public class MapController {

    private TemplateService templateService;

    public MapController(TemplateService templateService) {
        this.templateService = templateService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getName() throws Exception {
        return templateService.getTemplate("map.vm");
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() throws Exception {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use spring-boot-security-starter?

Comment: No, I don't use that.